# Why can't I eliminate this arrow function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, arrow-functions

I was convinced that the following 2 statements boiled down to the same thing.
But after refactoring the first statement to the 2nd I broke my application.

```
const myReader = new DataReader(line => this.onStdOutLine(line));
process.stdout.on('data', (data) => myReader.processData(data));
```

```
const myReader = new DataReader(line => this.onStdOutLine(line));
process.stdout.on('data', myReader.processData);
```

Why aren't these 2 the same thing ?

There is no `this` in these arrow functions, so it seemed harmless. As for the DataReader class itself:

```
type DataReaderCallback = (msg: string) => any

export class DataReader {
  private _buffer = "";

  constructor(private listener: DataReaderCallback = null) {
  }

  processData(data) {
    // remove carriage returns.
    data = data.toString().replace(/\r/g, '');
    this._buffer += data;

    // get only the complete data.
    const lastNewlineIndex = this._buffer.lastIndexOf('\n');
    if (lastNewlineIndex < 0) return;

    if (this.listener != null) {
      // split data in lines
      const completeData = this._buffer.slice(0, lastNewlineIndex);
      const lines = completeData.split('\n');
      for (const line of lines) {
        // notify listener line by line.
        this.listener(line);
      }
    }

    // remove processed data from the buffer.
    this._buffer = this._buffer.slice(lastNewlineIndex + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any `this` in `myReader.processor`? Does it work if you use `myReader.processor.bind(myReader)`? Could you provide more detail than *"broke"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I will add some more context - done

Comment: @jonrsharpe The DataReader is supposed to pass the input line-by-line to listeners. But these listeners are no longer called.

Comment: (+ thank you for the edit :) indeed processor = processData)

Comment: A replacement for `data => myReader.processData(data)` would be `myReader.processData.bind(myReader)`. Just `myReader.processData` isn't enough as it's called without a valid `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As for the DataReader class itself…

It **does** use `this`, e.g. `this._buffer += data;`

So the code that needs to call `processData` needs to ensure that `myReader` is the `this` value for it.

The arrow function does this by calling it as `myReader.processData(data)`.

If you pass the `processData` function as an argument to `on` then the event handling code *doesn't* call it in the context of `myReader`. It doesn't even know that `myReader` exists.

If you want to remove the arrow function, then you have to do something else to maintain the context of `myReader`.

You could use a function expression, or `bind`.

```
process.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
   myReader.processData(data);
});

process.stdout.on('data', myReader.processData.bind(myReader));
```

Comment: If I add a listener with `.on(foo.bar.bind(foo))`  , will I be able to remove listener (foo.bar) afterwards ? Or would I have to keep an exact reference to the `foo.bar.bind(foo)` to be able to remove it ?

Comment: `bind` creates a new function. If you want to remove *that* function then you need to keep a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks :) that answers it all. Seems like a silly question now. ;-)